# Изображения не отображаются в recyclerview из FireBase storage

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin, firebase

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Пожалуйста помогите! 3 день не могу понять причину)

CreatePost - здесь изображения отправляются в FireBase и добавляются в data класс Upload.

```
import android.content.ContentResolver;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.MimeTypeMap;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatEditText;

import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.storage.FirebaseStorage;
import com.google.firebase.storage.StorageReference;
import com.google.firebase.storage.StorageTask;

import butterknife.BindView;
import butterknife.ButterKnife;
import butterknife.OnClick;

public class CreatePost extends AppCompatActivity {

    @BindView(R.id.for_all)
    TextView all;
    @BindView(R.id.for_first)
    TextView first;
    @BindView(R.id.for_second)
    TextView second;
    @BindView(R.id.for_third)
    TextView third;
    @BindView(R.id.for_fourth)
    TextView fourth;
    @BindView(R.id.mini)
    ImageView mini;
    @BindView(R.id.appCompatEditText)
    AppCompatEditText text;

    private Uri mImageUri;
    private StorageReference storage;
    private DatabaseReference data;
    private String choose;
    private StorageTask mUploadTask;
    String uploadId;
    Upload upload;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_create_post);
        ButterKnife.bind(this);

        TeacherFeed teacherFeed = new TeacherFeed();
        teacherFeed.UnderlineSettings(all, first, second, third, fourth);

        storage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference("uploads");
    data = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("uploads");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if(requestCode == 1 && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data.getData() != null && data != null){
            mImageUri = data.getData();

            //Picasso.get().load(mImageUri).into(mini);
            Glide.with(this).load(mImageUri).into(mini);
            mini.setImageURI(mImageUri);
        }
    }

    @OnClick(R.id.image_select)
    public void OpenGallery(){
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        intent.setType("image/*");
        startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
    }
    @OnClick(R.id.info_help)
    public void Help(){
        new CustomBottomHelperGroup().show(getSupportFragmentManager(),"Dialog");
    }
    @OnClick(R.id.close_post)
    public void ClosePostCreater(){
        finish();
    }
    @OnClick(R.id.add_post)
    public void AddPost(){
        Upload();
        finish();
    }

    @OnClick(R.id.for_all)
    public void FilterAll(){
        choose = "0";
    }

    @OnClick(R.id.for_first)
    public void FilterFirst(){
        choose = "1";
    }

    @OnClick(R.id.for_second)
    public void FilterSecond(){
        choose = "2";
    }

    @OnClick(R.id.for_third)
    public void FilterThird(){
        choose = "3";
    }

    @OnClick(R.id.for_fourth)
    public void FilterFourth(){
        choose = "4";
    }

    private String getFileExtension(Uri uri) {
        ContentResolver cR = getContentResolver();
        MimeTypeMap mime = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton();
        return mime.getExtensionFromMimeType(cR.getType(uri));
    }

    private void Upload(){
        if (mImageUri != null) {

            StorageReference fileReference = storage.child(System.currentTimeMillis()
                    + "." + getFileExtension(mImageUri));

            mUploadTask = fileReference.putFile(mImageUri).addOnSuccessListener(taskSnapshot -> {

                upload = new Upload(text.getText().toString().trim(),
                    taskSnapshot.getMetadata().getReference().getDownloadUrl().toString());

            uploadId = data.push().getKey();
            data.child(uploadId).setValue(upload);

            }).addOnFailureListener(e -> Toast.makeText(this, "error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show());
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Не выбрано фото!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

RecyclerAdapter - отображает посты из базы данных FireBase

```
class RecyclerAdapter(private val context: Context, private val data: List<Upload>): RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder>() {

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
    val uploadCurrent = data[position]
    holder.mainText.text = uploadCurrent.name
    //Picasso.get().load(data[position].imageUrl).fit().centerCrop().placeholder(R.mipmap.ic_launch).into(holder.imageFeed)
    Glide.with(context).load(uploadCurrent.imageUrl).placeholder(R.drawable.scedule).centerCrop().into(holder.imageFeed)
}

override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
    val view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.recycler_content, parent, false)
    return ViewHolder(view)
}

override fun getItemCount() = data.size


class ViewHolder(val view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {

    val mainText: AppCompatTextView = view.findViewById(R.id.MainText)
    val imageFeed: ImageView = view.findViewById(R.id.ImageFeed)
}
```

}

AdministratorFeed - добавляет в список посты и отображает их

```
public class AdministratorFeed extends AppCompatActivity {

@BindView(R.id.all_post)
TextView all;
@BindView(R.id.first_post)
TextView first;
@BindView(R.id.second_post)
TextView second;
@BindView(R.id.third_post)
TextView third;
@BindView(R.id.fourth_post)
TextView fourth;
@BindView(R.id.toolbar)
Toolbar toolbar;

int check = 0;
int like_count;
AlertDialog.Builder ad;
boolean mode = false;
int num = 0;
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
String MODE = "MODE";

private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private DatabaseReference databaseReference;
private List<Upload> uploads;
private Upload upload;
private RecyclerAdapter adapter;
private ArrayList<Upload> list;
private FirebaseStorage mStorage;
private DatabaseReference mDatabaseRef;
private ValueEventListener mDBListener;

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    ad.show();
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu (Menu menu){
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected (MenuItem item){
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.dark_theme:
            if(num == 0){
                sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(MODE, MODE_PRIVATE);
                editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
                editor.putBoolean("MODE", mode = true);
                editor.apply();
                Handler handler = new Handler();
                handler.postDelayed(() -> AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES), 1000);
                num++;
            }else{
                sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(MODE, MODE_PRIVATE);
                editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
                editor.putBoolean("MODE", mode = false);
                editor.apply();
                Handler handler = new Handler();
                handler.postDelayed(() -> AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO), 1000);
                num--;
            }
            break;
        case R.id.error:
            new BottomError().show(getSupportFragmentManager(),"Dialog");
            break;
        case R.id.about:
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, AboutApp.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            break;
    }
    return true;
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_administrator_feed);
    ButterKnife.bind(this);
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
    toolbar.setTitle(" ");
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    showDialog();

    list = new ArrayList<>();

    recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recycler);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));


    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(MODE, MODE_PRIVATE);
    mode = sharedPreferences.getBoolean(MODE, mode);

    adapter = new RecyclerAdapter(AdministratorFeed.this, list);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

    mStorage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();
    mDatabaseRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("uploads");

    if(mode){
        AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES);
    }else{
        AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO);
    }

    TeacherFeed teacherFeed = new TeacherFeed();
    teacherFeed.UnderlineSettings(all, first, second, third, fourth);

    mDBListener = mDatabaseRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            list.clear();
            for(DataSnapshot snapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                Upload upload = snapshot.getValue(Upload.class);
                list.add(upload);
            }
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });

}
```

Upload - data класс

```
public class Upload {
private String mName;
private String mImageUrl;

public Upload() {

}

public Upload(String name, String imageUrl) {
    if (name.trim().equals("")) {
        name = "No Name";
    }

    mName = name;
    mImageUrl = imageUrl;
}

public String getName() {
    return mName;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    mName = name;
}

public String getImageUrl() {
    return mImageUrl;
}

public void setImageUrl(String imageUrl) {
    mImageUrl = imageUrl;
}
```

}

Лог ошибок:

```
    W/Glide: Load failed for com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzu@76e2bd2 with size [640x339]
    class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Failed to load resource
    There were 3 causes:
    java.io.FileNotFoundException(/com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzu@76e2bd2 (No such file or directory))
    java.io.FileNotFoundException(open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory))
    java.io.FileNotFoundException(open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory))
     call GlideException#logRootCauses(String) for more detail
      Cause (1 of 3): class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Fetching data failed, class java.io.InputStream, LOCAL
    There was 1 cause:
    java.io.FileNotFoundException(/com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzu@76e2bd2 (No such file or directory))
     call GlideException#logRootCauses(String) for more detail
        Cause (1 of 1): class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Fetch failed
    There was 1 cause:
    java.io.FileNotFoundException(/com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzu@76e2bd2 (No such file or directory))
     call GlideException#logRootCauses(String) for more detail
          Cause (1 of 1): class java.io.FileNotFoundException: /com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzu@76e2bd2 (No such file or directory)
      Cause (2 of 3): class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Fetching data failed, class android.os.ParcelFileDescriptor, LOCAL
    There was 1 cause:
    java.io.FileNotFoundException(open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory))
     call GlideException#logRootCauses(String) for more detail
        Cause (1 of 1): class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Fetch failed
    There was 1 cause:
    java.io.FileNotFoundException(open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory))
     call GlideException#logRootCauses(String) for more detail
          Cause (1 of 1): class java.io.FileNotFoundException: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
      Cause (3 of 3): class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Fetching data failed, class android.content.res.AssetFileDescriptor, LOCAL
    There was 1 cause:
    java.io.FileNotFoundException(open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory))
     call GlideException#logRootCauses(String) for more detail
        Cause (1 of 1): class java.io.FileNotFoundException: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
I/Glide: Root cause (1 of 3)
    java.io.FileNotFoundException: /com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzu@76e2bd2 (No such file or directory)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:200)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:150)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:103)
        at android.content.ContentResolver.openInputStream(ContentResolver.java:971)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.data.StreamLocalUriFetcher.loadResourceFromUri(StreamLocalUriFetcher.java:74)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.data.StreamLocalUriFetcher.loadResource(StreamLocalUriFetcher.java:50)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.data.StreamLocalUriFetcher.loadResource(StreamLocalUriFetcher.java:13)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.data.LocalUriFetcher.loadData(LocalUriFetcher.java:44)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.model.MultiModelLoader$MultiFetcher.loadData(MultiModelLoader.java:100)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.SourceGenerator.startNext(SourceGenerator.java:63)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodeJob.runGenerators(DecodeJob.java:310)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodeJob.runWrapped(DecodeJob.java:279)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodeJob.run(DecodeJob.java:234)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.executor.GlideExecutor$DefaultThreadFactory$1.run(GlideExecutor.java:431)
I/Glide: Root cause (2 of 3)
    java.io.FileNotFoundException: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
        at android.os.ParcelFileDescriptor.openInternal(ParcelFileDescriptor.java:313)
        at android.os.ParcelFileDescriptor.open(ParcelFileDescriptor.java:211)
        at android.content.ContentResolver.openAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:1248)
        at android.content.ContentResolver.openAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:1176)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.data.FileDescriptorLocalUriFetcher.loadResource(FileDescriptorLocalUriFetcher.java:20)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.data.FileDescriptorLocalUriFetcher.loadResource(FileDescriptorLocalUriFetcher.java:12)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.data.LocalUriFetcher.loadData(LocalUriFetcher.java:44)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.model.MultiModelLoader$MultiFetcher.loadData(MultiModelLoader.java:100)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.SourceGenerator.startNext(SourceGenerator.java:63)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodeJob.runGenerators(DecodeJob.java:310)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodeJob.onDataFetcherFailed(DecodeJob.java:408)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.SourceGenerator.onLoadFailed(SourceGenerator.java:130)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.model.MultiModelLoader$MultiFetcher.startNextOrFail(MultiModelLoader.java:167)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.model.MultiModelLoader$MultiFetcher.onLoadFailed(MultiModelLoader.java:154)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.data.LocalUriFetcher.loadData(LocalUriFetcher.java:49)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.model.MultiModelLoader$MultiFetcher.loadData(MultiModelLoader.java:100)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.SourceGenerator.startNext(SourceGenerator.java:63)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodeJob.runGenerators(DecodeJob.java:310)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodeJob.runWrapped(DecodeJob.java:279)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodeJob.run(DecodeJob.java:234)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.executor.GlideExecutor$DefaultThreadFactory$1.run(GlideExecutor.java:431)
I/Glide: Root cause (3 of 3)
    java.io.FileNotFoundException: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
        at android.os.ParcelFileDescriptor.openInternal(ParcelFileDescriptor.java:313)
        at android.os.ParcelFileDescriptor.open(ParcelFileDescriptor.java:211)
        at android.content.ContentResolver.openAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:1248)
        at android.content.ContentResolver.openAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:1176)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.data.AssetFileDescriptorLocalUriFetcher.loadResource(AssetFileDescriptorLocalUriFetcher.java:20)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.data.AssetFileDescriptorLocalUriFetcher.loadResource(AssetFileDescriptorLocalUriFetcher.java:11)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.data.LocalUriFetcher.loadData(LocalUriFetcher.java:44)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.SourceGenerator.startNext(SourceGenerator.java:63)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodeJob.runGenerators(DecodeJob.java:310)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodeJob.onDataFetcherFailed(DecodeJob.java:408)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.SourceGenerator.onLoadFailed(SourceGenerator.java:130)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.model.MultiModelLoader$MultiFetcher.startNextOrFail(MultiModelLoader.java:167)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.model.MultiModelLoader$MultiFetcher.onLoadFailed(MultiModelLoader.java:154)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.data.LocalUriFetcher.loadData(LocalUriFetcher.java:49)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.model.MultiModelLoader$MultiFetcher.loadData(MultiModelLoader.java:100)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.SourceGenerator.startNext(SourceGenerator.java:63)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodeJob.runGenerators(DecodeJob.java:310)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodeJob.onDataFetcherFailed(DecodeJob.java:408)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.SourceGenerator.onLoadFailed(SourceGenerator.java:130)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.model.MultiModelLoader$MultiFetcher.startNextOrFail(MultiModelLoader.java:167)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.model.MultiModelLoader$MultiFetcher.onLoadFailed(MultiModelLoader.java:154)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.data.LocalUriFetcher.loadData(LocalUriFetcher.java:49)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.model.MultiModelLoader$MultiFetcher.loadData(MultiModelLoader.java:100)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.SourceGenerator.startNext(SourceGenerator.java:63)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodeJob.runGenerators(DecodeJob.java:310)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodeJob.runWrapped(DecodeJob.java:279)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodeJob.run(DecodeJob.java:234)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.executor.GlideExecutor$DefaultThreadFactory$1.run(GlideExecutor.java:431)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы получить конкретное изображение можно сделать так:

`lateinit var dataBase: DatabaseReference`

`dataBase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Database").child("User1")`

`val listener = object :ValueEventListener{`
            override fun onCancelled(p0: DatabaseError) {

```
        }

        override fun onDataChange(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot) {

            val user1_image = dataSnapshot.child("user1_image").getValue().toString()
            Picasso.get().load(user1_image ).into(user1_img)
        }

    }

    dataBase.addValueEventListener(listener)
```

Если выводить данные в recyclerView, то нужен немного другой код.

upd: для recyclerView

```
// Переменные
```

`lateinit var recyclerView: RecyclerView`

`lateinit var dataBase: DatabaseReference`

`lateinit var layout: LinearLayoutManager`

```
// Загрузка данных с локального хранилища, если нет доступа к сети.
```

`// FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().setPersistenceEnabled(true)`

```
dataBase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Database")
recyclerView = findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.recyclerview)
layout = LinearLayoutManager(context)
recyclerView.layoutManager = layout

// Основной метод
```

`firebaseData()`

```
fun firebaseData() {

// Настройки. Этот вариант выводит все данные сразу. Есть еще немного другой вариант, который выводит конкретное кол-во значений в recyclerView и при прокрутке подгружает следующие элементы.

    val options = FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<Model>()
        .setLifecycleOwner(this)
        .setQuery(dataBase, Model::class.java)
        .build()

    val firebaseRecyclerAdapter =
        object : FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Model, CurrentNewsViewHolder>(options) {
            override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): CurrentViewHolder {
                val itemView = LayoutInflater.from(baseContext).inflate(R.layout.item, parent, false)
                return CurrentViewHolder(itemView)
            }

            override fun onBindViewHolder(p0: CurrentViewHolder, p1: Int, p2: Model) {

                dataBase.child(id).addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener {
                    override fun onCancelled(p0: DatabaseError) {
                        toast("Error")
                    }

                    override fun onDataChange(p: DataSnapshot) {                            

// Работа с элементами. p2 - это значения, которые мы получаем с БД. p0 - это значения, которые мы изменяем. К прмиеру p0.text.setText(p2.text).

                    }
                })

            }
        }

    recyclerView.adapter = firebaseRecyclerAdapter
    firebaseRecyclerAdapter.startListening()

}

// Тут пишем все элементы xml файла.

class CurrentViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {

    val view = itemView
    val text1:TextView = itemView.find(R.id.text1)        
}
```

```
// Модель данных. Если у Вас в БД есть поле text1, значит в моделе должна быть переменная text1. Регистр учитывается. Также, если у Вас String формат переменной, а в БД эта переменная со значением без " ", то будет ошибка.
```

`class Model_for_Current_News {`

```
var text1: String? = null

constructor() {

}

constructor(
    text1: String?
) {
    this.text1 = text1

}
```

}

Comment: Здравствуйте, спасибо за подсказку. Не могли бы вы написать для recyclerview код получения записей из firebase. Я не совсем понял из вашего кода как это сделать. Буду очень благодарен)

Comment: Добавил ответ в комментарий выше.